# `FastText.wv.save_word2vec_format()` creates some entries with two words on one line

Tags: gensim, fasttext

`FastText.wv.save_word2vec_format()` creates some entries with two words on one line.  This is a problem because it breaks the `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` function, which expects one word followed by `x` floats, where `x` is the number of dimensions in the vector.  I haven't been able to prove that this is a bug, so has anyone had this problem?

My solution has been to prune the resulting file by removing lines with two space-separated words.  In the large data sets that I used, there were between three and ten occurrences per data set.  I also double checked that no words in the vocabulary and no words in the data set contained a space.

In every occurrence, the two component words had their own entries as a single word. Is this intended for, maybe, particularly high co-occurring pairs?
Is this expected behavior?  If so, why?  And why is there no accounting for this in the loading function?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if `save_word2vec_format()` seems to have prefixed a particular line of floats with a string that includes more whitespace than just an ending space, then it is almost certain that the matching key in the model includes such whitespace.

In particular, consider a written file with the usual special header-line (containing the counts of further vectors & dimensionality), which on its 10th line (counting from 1 as if using `cat -n FILENAME`) shows this symptom. In such a case, I'd expect `ft_model.wv.index_to_key[8]` to reveal a key with a matching internal whitespace.

Are you sure this isn't the case for your occurrences? (How had you checked "that no words in the vocabulary and no words in the data set contained a space"? Might you have missed some more exotic whitespace character that somehow became a plain space while saving?)

If the actual key contains whitespace, the issue is that something in the prior preprocessing/training left such internal-whitespace tokens in the model, and solving that may be the best way to resolve the issue.

If not, there's a deeper problem & it'd be helpful to figure a minimal way to trigger the problem. Examining the `ft_model.wv.index_to_key` values for the keys all around the problem key might help narrow things down.

Comment: I will revisit this when I get a chance next week, but my initial investigation iterated through the keys in `wv` to look for whitespace, and found the offending occurrences.  I also searched the preprocessed documents for spaces, tabs, and newlines. It's possible (even probable) that exotic whitespaces were missed in the initial preprocessing, and that somewhere along the line after that they were converted to whitespace.  I will check back in here once I figure it out.  Thanks for the tips.